# Calling a servlet from an <li> via onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, servlets

I've been searching around for at least an hour and I haven't found anything like this. I'm trying to call a servlet method with an onclick function on an `<li>` element (in my navbar).

Basically I want the functionality of

```
<li>
    <form method="POST" action="HomeBservlet">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="profil">Profil
    </form>
</li>`
```

without the button (therefore the onclick).

This is something I found:

```
<li onclick="navbarForm.submit();">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Profil</a>
</li>
```

and it calls the servlet, but not the right function in it, leaving me with a blank page.

I can't seem to wrap my head around it, and I hope someone here knows what I'm looking for.

All help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: action should be like '/servlet/action' but you have only servlet part I guess...

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your form in a div, inside the <li>, and attaching an onclick to that??